# Converting decimal to specific scientific notation format

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I'm trying to convert decimal to a specific scientific notation format:

-2.802479940    ==>   -.2802479940E+01
3.796137791     ==>   0.3796137791E+01

And so on.  Basically, No leading zero on negative numbers and a leading zero 
on positive numbers. I've been able to print out in the big E scientific notation
but have no idea how to force the leading part to be a '-' or a '0' only.

Comment: Dunno how you'd do that in COBOL.  (You are writing in COBOL, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of ugly (there aren't any built-in [string-formatting options](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for it as far as I know), but it should do what you want it to do:

```
import re

nums = [-2.802479940, 3.796137791, -0.012, 0.035, 0, 100, -200]
decimal_digits = 10
for n in nums:
    num = ('{:.'+str(decimal_digits-1)+'E}').format(n)

    # increment exponent
    exp_search = re.search(r'E(\+|-)\d+', num).group()
    sign = exp_search[1]
    exp = int(exp_search[1:])
    new_exp = exp + 1
    exponent = 'E'+sign+'{:02}'.format(abs(new_exp))

    # move decimal place over
    sig_search = re.search(r'-?\d\.\d+', num).group()
    stripped = sig_search.replace('.', '')
    if stripped[0] == '-':
        significand = stripped.replace('-', '-.')
    else:
        significand = '0.' + stripped

    # glue significand and exponent back together
    new_num = significand + exponent
    print('{:>20}{:>20}'.format(num, new_num))
    assert float(num) == float(new_num)
```

Output:

```
    -2.802479940E+00    -.2802479940E+01
     3.796137791E+00    0.3796137791E+01
    -1.200000000E-02    -.1200000000E-01
     3.500000000E-02    0.3500000000E-01
     0.000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+01
     1.000000000E+02    0.1000000000E+03
    -2.000000000E+02    -.2000000000E+03
```

This doesn't perform any arithmetic, just string operations, so it shouldn't introduce any issues with floating-point representations or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here's C code to do what you want:

```
void numfmt(double d, char* buf) {
     int exp=0;
     int cont=1;
     char sign = '0';
     if (d < 0) {
         sign = '-';
         d = -d;
     }
     while(cont) {
         if (d >= 1.0) {
             exp ++;
             d /= 10.0;
         } else if (d < 0.1) {
             exp --;
             d *= 10.0;
         } else
             cont = 0;
     }
     sprintf(buf,"%12.10fE%+03d",d,exp);
     *buf = sign;
}
```

Comment: I'm stupid.  This is a great answer in C which I could use but I really meant python3.  There's, I think, some elegant easy way to do this in python3.  I've used a '%.10E' already to convert the decimal to scientific notation but need, as mentioned, no numbers to the left of the decimal place and only a -.231etc for negative numbers and a 0.231etc for positive numbers.  In fact I've already done this in an ugly way which probably to long to post.

Comment: I added a python tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To convert any number into scientific notation you need to know two things, the exponent and the decimal part. like this: Number = Dec E exponent (or Number = Dec * 10^exponent)

Log10() function will be really important then, cause it will give you the exact exponent of Number! Then to get the exponent you have this relation:

```
exponent = log10(Number/Dec)
```

but not knowing the Dec part, we will simplify into this relation:

```
exponent = log10(Number)
```

this will not give the integer exponent, only the exponent for which 1/10^exponent = Number. To get the right integer exponent you will need to get the first lowest integer with the floor() function.
That's why you'll need to change the relation to:

```
exponent = int(floor(log10(Number))) # using int will convert any floating value into an integer exponent
```

Then using this exponent you could easily find the decimal part with the relation:

```
Dec = Number / 10^exponent
```

Now you have a way to change any number* into scientific notation, if you need to have a leading zero, you then just have to decrement the exponent ^^
* Log(x) is defined on R*+ so if you have a negative number you must convert it into a positive one before passing it as an argument to log10(), and if the number is 0, then you should make an exception (return dec = 0 and exponent = 0)

this is an example of code in python:

```
Decompose(originalvalue):

    calcul = originalvalue;
    if (originalvalue != 0.0):
        if (originalvalue < 0):
            calcul = -calcul;
        exponent = int(floor(log10(calcul))); # get the integer exponent  
        value = originalvalue / 10.0**exponent; # get scientific decimal part
        # then to have a leading zero, you just have to verifiy if dec >= 1 or not, and in this case, modify the value and exponent to eliminate it.
        if (value >= 1):
            value *= 10**-1
            exponent += 1 
    else:
        exponent = 0;
        value = 0.0;
    return [value, exponent];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with, having the same problem.

```
def converter(number):

    number_str = '{:.14e}'.format(number)
    number_split = number_str.split('.')
    int_part = number_split[0]
    exp_part = number_split[1][-3:]
    dec_part = number_split[1][:-6]
    int_part_numeric = int(int_part)
    if number == 0:
        return '0.000000000000E+00'
    if int_part_numeric == 0:
        sign = '0'
        new_exp_part = exp_part
        new_dec_part = dec_part
    elif int_part_numeric < 0:
        sign = '-'
        new_exp_part = '{:+03d}'.format(int(exp_part) + 1)
        new_dec_part = int_part.strip('-') + dec_part[:-1]
    elif int_part_numeric > 0:
        sign = '0'
        new_exp_part = '{:+03d}'.format(int(exp_part) + 1)
        new_dec_part = int_part + dec_part[:-1]

    return sign + '.' + new_dec_part + 'E' + new_exp_part
```

It could probably be simplified a bit though...